# Add sub menu page in your plugin

Tags: plugins, filters, admin, wp-admin, hooks

this is how i am adding the menu and trying to add the sub menu page which is not adding.

**party-reservation.php**

```
function a_qoute_admin_action()
{
    add_menu_page(__('Reservations Pages'), __('Donation'), 'edit_themes', 'a-qoute', 'qoute_settings', ''); // working
    add_submenu_page("party-reservation.php", "Donations Log", "Donations Log", 8, "DonationsLog", "Donations_Log"); // not working.

}
add_action('admin_menu', 'a_qoute_admin_action');
```

if i use 'themes.php' it adds a sub menu page in the appearance section.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [add_submenu_page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_submenu_page) first parameter should be the top menu page handle which in you case is `a-qoute` so:

```
function a_qoute_admin_action(){
    add_menu_page(
        __('Reservations Pages'),// the page title
        __('Donation'),//menu title
        'edit_themes',//capability 
        'a-qoute',//menu slug/handle this is what you need!!!
        'qoute_settings',//callback function
        '',//icon_url,
        ''//position
    );
    add_submenu_page(
        'a-qoute',
        'Donations Log', //page title
        'Donations Log', //menu title
        'edit_themes', //capability,
        'DonationsLog',//menu slug
        'Donations_Log' //callback function
    );
}
add_action('admin_menu', 'a_qoute_admin_action');
```

Comment: ok now i got it.